# Função que lê um double de uma string e retorna o restante da string em C

Tags: c, string

Existe alguma função do tipo? Que lê e armazena ou retorna um double de uma string e retorna ou passa por ponteiro o restante da string ou terei de fazer a minha própria função? Caso não exista alguém tem ideias de como fazer essa função de modo otimizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe a função:

```
double strtod (const char* str, char** endptr);
```

Ela converte um número `double` a partir da string passada como primeiro parâmetro, e joga no segundo parâmetro um ponteiro para o resto da string. Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main ()
{
  char texto[] = "1.21 gigawatts";
  char* resto;
  double num;
  num = strtod (texto, &resto);
  printf ("Num: %f\n", num);
  printf ("Resto: %s\n", resto);
  return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Num: 1.210000
Resto:  gigawatts
```

Comment: Só para tirar uma ultima dúvida, usando a função strod(), tem alguma forma de o ponteiro recebido pelo resto ser o mesmo da string "principal" ou o melhor método de faze-lo é por um strcpy()?

Comment: Ele vai ser o "mesmo" sim. Internamente ele deve de apenas ir incrementando o ponteiro do primeiro parâmetro, e o escreve no segundo no fim.